# pdfkit changes href from relative to absolute paths on conversion

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using pdfkit to convert html files that have links with href attributes in them.

Inside of the html, href's are written with relative paths, e.g.:

```
<a href="folder/picture.jpg">PIC</a>
```

When I convert this to pdf, the hrefs seem to be automatically rewritten to absolute paths (`C:/Users/...`).

Why does pdf change the href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wkhtmltopdf, which pdfkit relies on, converts relative links to absolute links by default.

This can be stopped by using the command line tool with a special flag:

```
wkhtmltopdf --keep-relative-links src destination
```

Or by telling pdfkit to apply this option:

```
def convert_to_pdf(path):
    try:
        # run the conversion and write the result to a file
        config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
        options = {
            '--keep-relative-links': ''
        }
        pdfkit.from_url(path+'.htm', path+'.pdf', configuration=config, options=options)
    except Exception as why:
        # report the error
        sys.stderr.write('Pdf Conversion Error: {}\n'.format(why))
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you create a PDF out of an HTML file the PDF file will be opened on another location (for example on another computer after sending it via mail). So in order to reference correctly the full path is needed.

Of course this will only work if the other computer can access the path (so if the path is accessible from the other computer). With paths on C: this will only work from the localhost and not from other PCs.

Comment: I am planning to have a folder with all attachments in the same folder as the pdf file.  So, theoretically, there should be enough information for the file to be opened.  The html file works, in any case.

Comment: Thanks for trying but I think there was a misunderstanding.  I just posted the answer I was looking for, in case you're interested.

Comment: Maybe you should then ask a question which you want to have answered. You asked "Why does pdf change the href?" & I answered it!

Comment: Your answer states that 'the full path is needed', insinuating that the premise of my question is incorrect, i.e. that paths can be left relative.  You probably misread the question and thought I was talking about the path of the pdf I'm converting, not the links inside of the pdf, which can obviously be relative.

Comment: You did not ask whether it is possible to make the paths relative but you asked why they are absolute... but nevermind I'm happy you found the answer to your question...